# Deleted All Snapshots, Now Won't Boot VM with Snapshot not found error

Tags: vmware-esxi

I've just tried deleting the snapshots from this virtual machine running ESXI5, so that I can grow the Thick Partition. I've now got the below error message when I try to start the VM, the VM also can't be grown above 0 MB i assume for the same reason as below. I've checked the datastore and the original VMDK is still there.

```
Reason: The system cannot find the file specified.
Cannot open the disk 'VM1-PG-000002.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on. 
VMware ESX cannot find the virtual disk "VM1-PG-000002.vmdk". Verify the path is valid and try again.
```

How do i tell ESXI5 to use the proper VMDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the VMX file and point it to the correct vmdk.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still looking for `x-00001.vmdk`.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Danie's answer is correct, and I'd like to upvote it (if I had the reputation necessary) I found it very important to parse the .vmx file correctly.

In my case I had two disks, both scsi and was pulling my hair out until I realized I was pointing the wrong disk at the wrong .vmdk image.

Look for scsi0:0 and make sure that's pointing where it should.
Look for scsi0:1 and make sure that's pointing where *it* should.  In my case I was able to point scsi0:0 at the original base .vmdk image - so maybe I lost a few Windows updates or something, but more importantly I kept all my critical data safe and sound on scsi0:1